# 詰まり vs 即ち? Tsumari vs Sunawachi?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, words, nuances

Both seem very similar. In terms of explaining the previous line in the meaning of "namely" or "in the sense of" right?

Statement blabla ... tsumari/sunawachi, blabla.

Any particular difference to choose between either?

Comment: Related: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11120253156 , and these words are almost always written in kana, AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

Both can mean "namely" or "that is to say", but すなわち is clearly more formal and stiff. If an elementary school children used it in a casual conversation, probably I can't help laughing. つまり is a more common word that can be used in almost any situation.

You should usually write these in hiragana unless you intentionally want to make a stilted and old-fashioned sentence.